# sqlalchemy cannot drop table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I create my table use next code:

```
class tableName(self._dbHelper.DeclarativeBase):
                __tablename__ = "tableName"
                if not tableEngine is None:
                    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine' : tableEngine}
                first = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
                second = Column(String(45))
                third = Column(String(100))

                def __init__(self, second = Utils.uniqID(), third = Utils.uniqID()):
                    self.second = second
                    self.third = third
```

But then I'm trying to drop table, I got an error that tableName not contains method drop()
How can I drop this table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is next:

```
tableName.__table__.drop(self._engine)
```

More details are here: [Declarative doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html)